# There are $N+1$ urns, in $i$th urn there are $i$ white balls and $N-i$ red balls, $n$ draws from a rand urn gave red balls, prob next ball also red?

Tags: probability, summation, bayesian

The task:

> There are $N+1$ urns. In the $i$th urn there are $i$ white balls and $N-i$ red balls for $i=0,\ldots,N$. We choose a random urn and then we choose $n$ times a random ball from this urn with replacement. Assume that we drew a red ball each time. What is the probability that if we draw a ball from this urn one more time it will also be red?

My solution attempt:

First restate the task and say there are $i$ red balls and $N-i$ white balls, it doesn't matter but it will simplify calculations.

The probability to draw a red ball from the $i$th urn $n$ times is: $\operatorname{P}(R_{1,\ldots,n}|U_i)=\left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^n$

The probability to choose $i$th urn for any $i$ is: $\operatorname{P}(U_i)=\frac1{N+1}$

The probability to draw a red ball from a random urn $n$ times is: $\operatorname{P}(R_{1,\ldots,n})=\sum_{i=0}^N\operatorname{P}(U_i)\operatorname{P}(R_{1,\ldots,n}|U_i)=\sum_{i=0}^N\frac1{N+1}\left(\frac iN\right)^n=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{N}i^n}{(N+1)N^n}$

The probability that we chose the $i$th urn provided we drew a red ball $n$ times is: $\operatorname{P}(U_i|R_{1,\ldots,n})=\frac{\operatorname{P}(U_i)\operatorname{P}(R_{1,\ldots,n}|U_i)}{\operatorname{P}(R_{1,\ldots,n})}=\frac{\frac1{N+1}\left(\frac iN\right)^n}{\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{N}j^n}{(N+1)N^n}}=\frac{i^n}{\sum_{j=0}^Nj^n}$

The fact that we've already drawn $n$ red balls from an urn doesn't affect the probability that we draw one more red ball, so $\operatorname{P}((R_{n+1}|R_{1,\ldots,n})|(U_i|R_{1,\ldots,n}))=\operatorname{P}(R_{n+1}|U_i)=\frac iN$

The probability that the $n+1$th ball will also be red is: $\operatorname{P}(R_{n+1}|R_{1,\ldots,n})=\sum_{i=0}^N\operatorname{P}(U_i|R_{1,\ldots,n})\operatorname{P}((R_{n+1}|R_{1,\ldots,n})|(U_i|R_{1,\ldots,n}))=\sum_{i=0}^N\frac{i^n}{\sum_{j=0}^Nj^n}\frac iN=\frac{\sum^N_{i=0}i^{n+1}}{N\sum_{i=0}^Ni^n}$

Here is where I'm stuck.

According to answers for my other questions here ([(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589177/for-given-k-n-in-mathbbn-how-to-compute-sum-i-0nik), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590236/for-given-k-n-in-mathbbn-how-to-compute-frac-sumn-i-0ik1-sumn)) this is not easily solvable. Granted I've forgotten much from my former basic courses on mathematical analysis and discrete mathematics - nevertheless, these were basic courses - I'm pretty sure I haven't had any Riemann zeta functions. However, I did have integrals and generating functions and I don't remember much from these topics.

Which is why I don't believe that a solution involving Riemann zeta functions is the expected one. However, I find it possible that the expected solution involves some kind of a crude approximation, [akin to the ones that were already present at this course](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584405/why-can-we-maximize-frack-1n-mathrmh-n-1-mathrmh-k-2-for-2-le).

How to move on with this task? Or, where is my error in the above solution attempt, if there is any?

Comment: This is a tough one. Is it possible the closed-form formula you came up with would be sufficient?

Comment: @Wes I doubt it. However, I suppose an estimation might.

Comment: Why $(N+1)$ urns, and what will the $(N+1)_{th}$ urn contain ?

Comment: @trueblueanil The urns are $0$-indexed. So the last urn is the $N$th urn, not $(N+1)$th.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, thanks !